# Usefulness of a "playing with open cards" strategy about the wage on a job interview?

Tags: job-offer

If they ask, what would be your idea about the wage. In this case normally I play with open cards, similar to this: "Before you I earned between X and Y, and my goal to have an increasing trend on the longterm".

Actually, this is the truth. If I get a new job, I want at least a little bit better wage as the previous was.

Actually, this question isn't about the wage maximization, but from the usefulness of this "playing with open cards" strategy.

Is it a good strategy, or not? Why?

Comment: @gnat They are _not_ duplicates, this question is _much_ more specific. It targets exclusively this "open cards" strategy, and it is not about the wage game in general. I tried to make this in my question more clear - please remove your duplicate flag, if you can.

Comment: @gnat Yes, it "looks like" if you interpret the word "like" enough widely. But actually, this question doesn't target the "open card strategy", just as your first duplicate candidate didn't targeted. My ask were to remove that "maybe duplicate" flag, because they aren't duplicates.

Comment: Useful to what end: Getting an offer, getting what you want to be paid, being a way to diffuse tension in the interview or something else? There are more than a few objectives one could have here though I wonder if this is understood.

Comment: @gnat This was evil, shame on you.

Comment: @JBKing For both. The chance of the job offer, and the possible biggest are both important goals on a job interview.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Smart employers generally want to hire people that will stay around a while.  Turnover is very expensive in both direct and indirect costs, so they will research the market values for positions closely matched to what you will be doing, and strive to start your pay off at something slightly above or slightly below whatever they have pegged as the market value for the position.  Slightly more if your experience warrants, and slightly less if you perhaps have some room to grow into being fully functional in the position.

*Some* employers will want to know what you are making now, and then offer you a small increase to join their firm.  This isn't a good strategy for the reasons mentioned above.  If you accept compensation that is substantially below market, eventually you will figure it out and leave  - driving more turnover.

Your strategy is sound.  Be honest about what you are making now and what you think the position (and you) are worth. Be very careful about using salary data you find for free on the web - it's often unrealistic. Be respectful, polite and appreciative of any consideration you receive during negotiations.  Hopefully together you can arrive at a number that works for both of you. And don't forget, base salary is only one element of compensation - your decision making needs to take into account the whole package.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem is that you have two holes in your response. You have given a range and stated that you want at least a little better wage.

Therefore 1% above the lower value is an increase.

The words you use make little difference unless you know what the range of possible pay and benefits are.

In most places there is a maximum amount they can pay for the the position you are applying for. If you are far above that maximum value you will have to lower your demand if you want the position. There is also a minimum they will pay.

If you hit in their range and give them a single number you will likely get some sort of a bump. If you give them a range they will look at how it overlaps their range and they may or may not give you a bump.

For example if they will pay 50 to 55 an hour, and you state you made

- "Before you I earned between 45 and 50, and my goal to have an increasing trend on the longterm". You will probably get an offer at the bottom of their range.
- "Before you I earned between 60 and 65, and my goal to have an increasing trend on the longterm". You will probably not get what you want.
- "Before you I earned between 50 and 55, and my goal to have an increasing trend on the longterm". You will get something in the middle of the range.

When they have a choice they will put you either at the lowend of the range, or the middle of the range. They know that if they start you at the top there is zero room for wage growth.

Comment: It's also worth noting the differences in jobs past matters. If the change is within tolerance of what they expect to pay in the way of raises. (each shift put you at a 3-8% increase) no problem! But if each shift was a 20% increase I'd assume in a year or two I need to pay you 20% more or you'll just leave for someone that will... I can't think of any employers ready and/or willing to pay bump someone's salary up 20% year over year.

Answer (score -3):

I think it's a good strategy.

The company asks this to get a sincere offer from you, and based on that they can get to a conclusion:

- You don't know what you're worth by naming a salary too low;
- You know what you're worth by naming a salary fitting to the job & experience;
- You know what you're worth, but you're naming a salary way higher than is fitting.

9/10 times, the company knows what you're worth. They've done background checks regarding salary scales for the job and experience. By telling your previous wage, they can compare the salaries and conclude whether it's accurate or not.

Comment: -1: `By telling your previous wage...` Your current wage is your business. Your future wage is your future employer's business.